# Setting up Pycharm to aid in learning python itself.

Tags: pycharm

Can Pycharm be configured to help learn python itself? I have pycharm setup right now and I'm trying to see its possible to set it up to help me learn more about the language. For example, and this is a simple example, lets say I created an empty list:

list = []

If I highlight over [] or control-click on it, pycharm tells me nothing about lists or anything about the brackets. Is it possible to set it up so that I can get to the official python documentation that talks about lists or anything that indicates its a list in the first place? I see that the official python documentation is not added to Pycharm's default external documents under Pycharms settings. If I add it, how to I pull it up for objects, sequence types, methods and all the other things that makes python tick? Pycharm is an awesome IDE and I have to believe its possible to set it up so the language itself it easier to learn when working in it.

Answer (score 1):

At this time PyCharm is only able to provide help for library functions; it doesn't have any features for providing help on language features such as list literals.